# Unable to set up discord bot to get connected will not set up authentication token

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm following a tutorial to set up a discord bot with python and am using Python IDLE shell 3.9.6
So, far I'm just trying to get the bot to connect but am running into issues with it accepting my key and after changing where it is calling to access the bot key. Which I have saved as the .env file type

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("---.env")
TOKEN = os.getenv()

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
 async def on_ready():
  print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Error Message:

```
 line 8, in <module>
 TOKEN = os.getenv()
TypeError: getenv() missing 1 required positional argument: 'key'
```

Comment: What variable did you set in the .env file? Suppose you wanted to set `FOO` to `Bar`. You would check it with `os.getenv('FOO') == 'Bar'`. `getenv` will get one named environment variable.

Comment: Before `os.getenv`, you could `print(open("---.env").read())` to show us what's in the environment.

Comment: So, the .env file has my bot token code in it. So, the point would be for the command Token = os.getenv() to retreive the token without me just putting the token striaght up in the bot file. in the env file it is set as:
DISCORD_TOKEN={}

Answer (score 0):

**os.getenv()** method in Python returns the value of the environment variable key.
You need to specify which key you want to grab from the env file, for example:

`TOKEN = os.getenv(foo)`

`TOKEN = os.getenv(my_key)`

From what I read in the comments your key is DISCORD_TOKEN so

`TOKEN = os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN)`